# Can I use the TableDrivenTests concept in C++?

Tags: c++, testing

I know that in **Go** it is commonly used what is called [TableDrivenTests](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests) to implement test cases, for example:

```golang
func TestMyFunc(t *testing.T) {
    var tTable = []struct {
        input  []float64
        result float64
    }{
        {[]float64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 102.896},
        {[]float64{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 576.0},
        {[]float64{9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 0.0},
    }

    for _, pair := range tTable {
        result := MyFunc(pair.input)
        assert.Equal(t, pair.result, result)
    }
}
```

> Given a table of test cases, the actual test simply iterates through
>   all table entries and for each entry performs the necessary tests.

I really like this **Go** style for implementing tests. So I want to know, is it possible to use something similar to it in **C++**? If it is possible, can you show me an example?

**Edit**: I'm using **Qt Creator** and I have a class created to perform unit tests. What I actually want to know is if it is possible to create a struct with the **inputs** and **outputs** and iterate through the entries to perform each test. As I'm using Qt it doesn't need to be a 'standard C++ struct', it can be another data structure provided by Qt.

Comment: Not using Standard C++, because it doesn't have anything unit tests. You will have to find a library for that.

Comment: Thanks @Rakete1111. I have edited my question.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an almost 1:1 translation to C++:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// Testable function.
double MyFunc(const std::vector<double> &input)
{
    static double results[] = { 102.896, 576.0, 0.0 };
    static int i = 0;
    return results[i++]; // return different results
}

// Our test. Returns true if passes.
bool TestMyFunc()
{
    struct
    {
        std::vector<double> input;
        double result;
    } tTable[] =
    {
        {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 102.896},
        {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 576.0},
        {{9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 0.0},
    };

    for ( const auto &pair : tTable ) {
        auto result = MyFunc(pair.input);
        if ( result != pair.result )
            return false; // return false if test fails
    }

    return true; // all test cases passed
}

int main() {
    std::cout << TestMyFunc() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

But I would recommend to use existing unit-testing frameworks, e.g. [gtest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md) has a concept of [value parametrised tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#value-parameterized-tests), which is approximately what you want.

Comment: ninja-ed me by 9 min.... :) ... and yours more complete and a bit more polished, nice. At least I went for almost identical `tTable` struct (with result first, that's more idiomatic in unit tests, the "expected" value resides usually on left side, inputs and calculations are on right side). Now I see the  OP originally organized it like that, so .... just a pointless suggestion for OP maybe.